# Can't install any Kernel in 23.10

Tags: kernel, 23.10

After updating to 23.10 I can't install the new Kernel. I got the following error:

````
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.5.0-10-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Signing key: /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv
Public certificate (MOK): /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
make -j8 KERNELRELEASE=6.5.0-10-generic -C /lib/modules/6.5.0-10-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/xone/v0.3-1-g2467407/build...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for xone: v0.3-1-g2467407 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-10-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/xone/v0.3-1-g2467407/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.5.0-10-generic/x86_64 succeeded for nvidia xpad
dkms autoinstall on 6.5.0-10-generic/x86_64 failed for xone(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
 * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.5.0-10-generic
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes linux-headers-6.5.0-10-generic (--configure):
 »installiertes post-installation-Skript des Paketes linux-headers-6.5.0-10-generic«-Unterprozess gab den Fehlerwert 1 zurück
dpkg: Abhängigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04:
 linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04 hängt ab von linux-headers-6.5.0-10-generic; aber:
  Paket linux-headers-6.5.0-10-generic ist noch nicht konfiguriert.

dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04 (--configure):
 Abhängigkeitsprobleme - verbleibt unkonfiguriert
Es wurde kein Apport-Bericht verfasst, da das Limit MaxReports bereits erreicht ist.
                                                                                    Es wurde kein Apport-Bericht verfasst, da das Limit MaxReports bereits erreicht ist.
                                                                                                                                                                        dpkg: Abhängigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von linux-generic-hwe-22.04:
 linux-generic-hwe-22.04 hängt ab von linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04 (= 6.5.0.10.12); aber:
  Paket linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04 ist noch nicht konfiguriert.

dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes linux-generic-hwe-22.04 (--configure):
 Abhängigkeitsprobleme - verbleibt unkonfiguriert
dpkg: Abhängigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von linux-headers-generic:
 linux-headers-generic hängt ab von linux-headers-6.5.0-10-generic; aber:
  Paket linux-headers-6.5.0-10-generic ist noch nicht konfiguriert.

dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes linux-headers-generic (--configure):
 Abhängigkeitsprobleme - verbleibt unkonfiguriert
dpkg: Abhängigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von linux-generic:
 linux-generic hängt ab von linux-headers-generic (= 6.5.0.10.12); aber:
  Paket linux-headers-generic ist noch nicht konfiguriert.

dpkg: Fehler beim BeaEs wurde kein Apport-Bericht verfasst, da das Limit MaxReports bereits erreicht ist. ```




the output from /var/lib/dkms/xone/v0.3-1-g2467407/make.log





``` DKMS make.log for xone-v0.3-1-g2467407 for kernel 6.5.0-10-generic (x86_64)
Fr 27. Okt 07:49:53 CEST 2023
make: Verzeichnis „/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-10-generic“ wird betreten
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-4ubuntu3) 13.2.0
  You are using:           gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-4ubuntu3) 13.2.0
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/xone/v0.3-1-g2467407/build/transport/wired.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/xone/v0.3-1-g2467407/build/transport/dongle.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/xone/v0.3-1-g2467407/build/transport/mt76.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/xone/v0.3-1-g2467407/build/bus/bus.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/xone/v0.3-1-g2467407/build/bus/protocol.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/xone/v0.3-1-g2467407/build/driver/common.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/xone/v0.3-1-g2467407/build/driver/gamepad.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/xone/v0.3-1-g2467407/build/driver/headset.o
/var/lib/dkms/xone/v0.3-1-g2467407/build/bus/bus.c:91:19: error: initialization of ‘int (*)(const struct device *, struct kobj_uevent_env *)’ from incompatible pointer type ‘int (*)(struct device *, struct kobj_uevent_env *)’ [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
   91 |         .uevent = gip_client_uevent,
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/xone/v0.3-1-g2467407/build/bus/bus.c:91:19: note: (near initialization for ‘gip_client_type.uevent’)
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:251: /var/lib/dkms/xone/v0.3-1-g2467407/build/bus/bus.o] Fehler 1
make[2]: *** Auf noch nicht beendete Prozesse wird gewartet …
make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-10-generic/Makefile:2037: /var/lib/dkms/xone/v0.3-1-g2467407/build] Fehler 2
make: *** [Makefile:234: __sub-make] Fehler 2
make: Verzeichnis „/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-10-generic“ wird verlassen ```
````

Comment: Please can you add `dkms status` to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I faced with a similar issue today. If you have upgraded from a previous version of Ubuntu, try these commands:

```
sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean
```

After that, try:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

Hope this helps you.